# Unity object.transform.posistion returns low numbers?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity so I dont really know whats going wrong.

I made a parent and a child.
The parent rotates.
The child is off centered.

Now I want to get the position of the child. This means I used ob.transform.position . But when I didnt rotate the parent ob.transform.position should give me the same as in inspector of the child, right?

but it doesnt ... It gives me position devided by 60.

**What did I wrong?**

Comment: instead of '.position' try '.localPosition'?

Comment: @Mr.Banks this gives me the correct positions until I rotate the parent. It will always gives me the position relative to its parent

Comment: What you see in the Inspector is the child position relative to the parent, in its local coordinate system, you access it via `child.transform.localPosition`. On the other hand `child.transform.position` gives you the absolute global world space position. Now if the latter is always divided by 60 it means that your parent object seems to have an absolute (lossy) scale of `0.017` so the coordinate system of the child objects is scaled down

Answer (score 0):

When a transform (let's call it `child`) is a child of a parentTransform (let's call it `parent`), the `child` is now pivoted to the `parent`.

> But when I didnt rotate the parent ob.transform.position should give me the same as in inspector of the child, right?

This assumption is **incorrect**.

The only way the `parent` and `child` `transform.position` values will be the same is IF they are totally in the same position/aligned. Which would show that the `child`'s `localPosition` is set to `(0,0,0)`.

The fact that the `child` is off-centered from the `parent` means that they aren't in the same position, and their respective `transform.position` values will be different.

Answer (score -1):

You can get all children by function:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform meeple;
    public GameObject grandChild;

    public void Example()
    {
        //Assigns the transform of the first child of the Game Object this script is attached to.
        meeple = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0);

        //Assigns the first child of the first child of the Game Object this script is attached to.
        grandChild = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question in any way